# Expand window to free space on screen in KDE

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, window-manager, window, window-buttons

I am using Kubuntu, and I want to expand the current window to the free space on the screen.  To say it more precisely:  I want to make the current window as big as possible without overlapping new windows (windows already overlapped should be ignored).

Is there a keyboard shortcut or an extension to the KDE Window Manager that makes such a shortcut or a window button?

I would also appreciate a hint, how to write a script that could do this window thing on keyboard shortcut invocation. I am a programmer but don't know what the best way is to control KDE Windows via script.

Comment: It looks like the way to go might be to script kwin.

Answer (score 3):

So, I wanted to avoid the classic "someone else had this problem but no one has answered this" google result. I'm not an Ubuntu/Kubuntu user but I found that the behaviour you desire has been in the bug reports for almost 9 years for KDE. It turns out that with the way KWin is written it would be very difficult to implement (or perhaps no devs want to tackle it).

Anyway. Here's the bug report for any future googlers who come by:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78984